# How to suppress Makefile $(info) and $(warning) output messages during make?

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I tried make -s, that only affects echo, info and warning still outputs. Somebody knows how to suppress that message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `make > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit that Makefile, you could surround these calls with a conditional block like this:

```
ifneq ($(DEBUG),)
$(info ...)
$(warning ...)
endif
```

And then call make like this to enable them:

```
make DEBUG=1
```

Comment: It may take time, but still it'll work. I don't know any other solution, since there are no flags that can disable these commands.